# How to find limit of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x}{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence

How should I argue more strictly for the divergence of the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x}{x^2}$$
Looking at it, it's easy to see $e^x\rightarrow1$ and $1/x^2 \rightarrow \infty$, so it must diverge. But I'm implicitly using the rule $\lim_{x \to 0} [f(x)g(x)]=\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) \lim_{x \to 0}g(x)$.  But if I remember the rule correctly, I can't use the product rule unless both functions converges.

So how do I argue more correctly for the divergence (Without using epsilon, delta etc. definitions).

Comment: @Koro Yes, then it's pretty easy to see. But the issue is that taylor series is not part of the curriculum yet. So is there another way to evaluate the limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\ln(0.5)$ is negative, and that if $\ln(0.5)<x$ then $\frac{1}{2} < e^x$. So, for any $\ln(0.5)< x$, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2x^2} < \frac{e^x}{x^2}.
\end{align}
Now, by letting $x\to 0$, we see that the LHS $\to \infty$, hence the RHS $\to \infty$ as well.

---

More generally, if you have two functions $f$ and $g$, such that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x) =l \neq 0$, and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x) = \infty$, then you can show that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)g(x) = \text{sign}(l)\cdot\infty$.

Here, we can allow for the possibility of $a,l$ being $\pm \infty$ (but it is important that $l\neq 0$, otherwise the result is false; take $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $a=0$).

Answer (score 2):

$e^x$ is continuous at $0$ and takes the value $1$. Therefore for $x$ close to $0$, $e^x>1/2$. Hence $$\frac{e^x}{x^2} > \frac{1}{2x^2}\to \infty.$$